# Deferred from within XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, deferred

I am using [this implementation of `Deferred`](https://github.com/sudhirj/simply-deferred)

strange thing - when I nest them in each other like that:

```
foo2 = ->  
   d = new Deferred()
   setTimeout ->
      d.resolve("I am foo2")
   ,400

   d.promise()

foo1 = ->
  d = new Deferred()
  setTimeout -> 
     foo2().then (res)->
        console.log(res)
        d.resolve("I am foo1")
  ,500

  d.promise()

foo1.done (res)-> console.log(res)
```

it works.

But if I try resolving deferred in `xhr`, that makes `xhr` call in its turn - it doesn't work:

```
foo2 = ->
   d = new Deferred()
   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
   xhr.open('GET', "http://blabla.com/some_other.json", true)
   xhr.onreadystatechange = ->
      d.resolve("I am foo2") if xhr.readyState is 4 and xhr.status is 200


   xhr.send()
   d.promise()

foo1 = ->
   d = new Deferred()
   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
   xhr.open('GET', "http://blabla.com/some.json", true)
   xhr.onreadystatechange = f->
     if xhr.readyState is 4 and xhr.status is 200
        foo2().then (res)-> # It calls foo2 but never resolves its deferred
           console.log(res)
           d.resolve("I am foo1")

   xhr.send()
   d.promise()

foo1.then (res)-> console.log(res)
```

Strangely, if I change `foo2` in second example and use a callback, everything works just fine.

Comment: I see a glance of coffeescript there?

Comment: Well, maybe the call to `http://blabla.com/` doesn't succeed? You're not rejecting the deferred in an error case either.

Comment: no..no the urls I'm using are legit... this blabla.com just as an example

Comment: Still, can you confirm that the readystate-handler is getting called and actually resolves your deferred?

Comment: Btw, you forgot some closing braces for the readystate handlers. If you're better with coffeescript, feel free to post it…

Comment: Yes, readystate is called... if I change foo2 and use callback instead it works

Comment: yeah initially I typed the question using coffeescript, but then thought it may piss some people off... switched back to coffee :)

Comment: It's still pissing me off.

Comment: ok... I'll use closurescript next time :)